What did "Price Fourpence The Three" mean?
From the cover of a 1842 book published in Manchester and London (The Three Prize Essays on Agriculture and the Corn Law):

What did the above mean? (In particular what did "the Three" mean?)

The title starts with "The Three Prize Essays", and you're asking what the three are? They're the essays.

Seems like this is perhaps more appropriate to English.SE

The price of "the three" is fourpence. They have left out some parts of the sentence; you could read it as "(The) price (is) fourpence (for) the three (items)".
A fourpence was an old coin in the UK worth 1/60th of a pound sterling and was equivalent to four pennies (pence is the plural for penny in UK English, hence sixpence (sing a song of sixpence...), fourpence, tuppence (two pence), etc.). The fourpence was minted from 1836 to 1855 and 1888, so you are right in the early part of that time-frame for use of the term.
"The three", as commented by BrianZ are the three essays combined into one book. Possibly you could get each essay as a single publication, but I can not find any mention of this in the articles I read. The Anti-Corn Law League published some nine million copies of tracts during its campaign to abolish the Corn laws, so single copies may well have been available, though I can't see any versions on Archive.org other than the combined book with the three authors George Hope, William Rathbone Greg, and Arthur Morse.

The spelling was pound sterling. The fact of the existence of a fourpence coin (called a 'groat') is irrelevant; a buyer could have used any combination of threepences, pennies, halfpennies, or farthings to make up 4d, or paid with a coin of higher value and received change.

@MichaelHarvey Quite right any combination could be used, but the conjunction of the words implies the use of the coin I believe.

I don't see that at all. 'Fourpence', 'sixpence', 'elevenpence', etc, are prices, not amounts represented by single coins. Are you suggesting the that 'Price Fourpence the Three' implies that only groats are acceptable? Not four pennies? Because that's nonsense. Sorry to put it that way, but there you are.
